Recuperando ancho y alto de un JLabel para escalar imagen de un icono
Estoy teniendo problemas con el código siguiente:
labAboutImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new  
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/MyProject/resources/img01.jpg"))
        .getImage().getScaledInstance(labAboutImage.getWidth(), 
labAboutImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));

donde labAboutImage es un JLabel.
Generando el error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero

Este JLabel pertenece a un JDialog y no al JFrame principal. El mismo código funciona bien si en vez de usar un JLabel del diálogo, se usa un JLabel perteneciente a la ventana principal. El código está ubicado en el constructor de la ventana principal (JFrame) después de la llamada a initComponents().
Creo que el error es provocado porque en ese punto del código, las dimensione del JLabel no han sido seteadas todavía, pero no estoy seguro de dónde ubicar el código. Por ejemplo, si el mismo código se pone en el evento ComponentShown del JDialog, todo funciona bien, pero entonces el código se ejecutaría innecesariamente cada vez que el diálogo se abra.
Gracias.

El problema que tienes se debe a que cuando intentas obtener el ancho y alto del JLabel, las dimensiones aún no han sido calculadas porque el componente no ha sido completamente renderizado. Por eso obtienes un error de dimensiones cero.
La solución es usar un ComponentListener, que permite esperar hasta que el JLabel haya sido mostrado y entonces tomar sus dimensiones. Así puedes escalar la imagen correctamente solo una vez, en lugar de hacerlo cada vez que se muestra el diálogo como indicas.
labAboutImage.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            // Se asegura de que solo se ejecute una vez, cuando las dimensiones sean mayores que 0
            if (labAboutImage.getWidth() > 0 && labAboutImage.getHeight() > 0) {
                // Carga la imagen original
                ImageIcon originalIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tu_Proyecto/rsc/image.jpg"));
    
                // Escala la imagen según el tamaño del JLabel
                Image scaledImage = originalIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(
                        labAboutImage.getWidth(), labAboutImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    
                // Establece el icono escalado en el JLabel
                labAboutImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaledImage));
    
                // Remueve el listener una vez que el icono ha sido establecido
                labAboutImage.removeComponentListener(this);
            }
        }
    });

